# Access a javascript object value

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use a JavaScript object reference to dynamically call different values of an array. Here is tje code  i have

```
//A static call to the object that works and retutns a value
var sam = (obj.Matt); 
console.log(sam)
```

However, if i do something like this, I am returned an undefined variable from the console log. Theoretically, the variable trent will change based on key in array.

```
//A dynamic reference
var trent = "Matt";
var sam = obj.trent
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
var sam = obj.trent   // "dot notation"
```

to this:

```
var sam = obj[trent]; // array index notation
```

Because variables can't be used in standard "dot notation", but they can be used to pass a string into an object and look up the property (key) with that string name.

Comment: don't forget the quotes: var sam = obj['Trent'];

Comment: Faster to find one of the 10or more dupes than to answer @pro you are wrong

Comment: @pro No. You don't put quotes there. That's the point. `trent` is a variable that holds a string.